# get the properties of a list of objects dynamically?

Tags: c#

I have a list of c# objects and each object has 100 properties:

```
public string Group1;
public string Group2;
public string Group3;

.....................
...
..
.
public string Group99;
public string Group100;
```

I want to be able to pass in two numbers in the range of 1 to 100 and only get the properties that fall in between that range.

for example if i pass in the number 31 to 50 i would want the properties:

```
public string Group31;
public string Group32;

....................
...
..
.
public string Group50;
```

how would I be able to achieve this?

Comment: Just to check this is just sample code and your actual code is more complex? At the moment the above looks like you are better off with a dictionary holding strings rather than this. Also Whether the property names are uniform like this will likely make a difference to the answer...

Comment: Those are fields. Do you *actually* have fields, or do you have properties? And why don't you just have a collection instead?

Comment: You will need a `Reflection` for this task. However array or list usage looks much more appropriate, as said above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you have fields, so you can use reflection and LINQ like this:

```
//pass your class to typeof
var ClssType = typeof (SomeCLass);
ClssType.GetFields().OrderBy(n=>n.Name).Skip(30).Take(19).ToList();
```

In Skip you passing numbers that you want to skip befaure taking fields.

If you had properties you could use `.GetProperties()` instead of `.GetFields()`

For getting values of your properties you need to call `.GetValue(obj, null)` for every object in your array.

```
   //let say you have array of objects myObj[] then your code will look like this:
   var fieldsInfos = ClssType.GetFields().OrderBy(n=>n.Name).Skip(30).Take(19).ToList();
   //go thorugh your array
   foreach(var obj in myObj)
   { 
       //go through fields
       foreach(var field in fieldsInfos)
       {
           //get value of field by calling
           Console.WriteLine(field.GetValue(obj, null));
        }     
   }
```

Comment: do I have to do this on each object or can I apply this to all the objects in the list?

Comment: Are you sure that GetFields will return sorted fields array? Otherwise direct skip/take will make no sense.

Comment: Are you sure that OrderBy will sort list not like P1, P10, .., P2, P20, ..?

Comment: There is one more caveeat: fields names in OP sample are not use digits padding and default sorting will be not `natural`, so order will be field1, field10, field11, field2, field20; so additionally you'll need to create "natural" implementation of IComparer, since there is no built-in in .net. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/248603/natural-sort-order-in-c-sharp

Comment: That's why Chris and Jon Skeet recommended to use generic collection for op's task.

Comment: Yes, now I see the problems of my algorithm, thank you for your clarifications.